# How to re-factor a common String comparison

Tags: java, strings

Code below is scattered all over the code base :

```
if (StringUtils.contains(manager.getName, "custom")){

}
```

It just checks if an object attribute contains a predefined String and if it does, enter condition.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving above, perhaps using an enum?

Comment: Is the string being searched for always the same?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph yes its always the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It seems [data envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy). I'd create `nameContains` method in the `Manager` class.

   ```
   public boolean nameContains(final String searchText) {
       if (StringUtils.contains(name, searchText)) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. Instance variables (fields) should be private. See: [why instance variables in java are always private](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622781/843804)

Comment: `if (cond) return true; else return false;` => `return cond;`

Comment: +1 for the link to data envy. However, as Konrad suggested, the body of this method should be a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `static` reference for "custom" :

```
    // In References.class declared 'final'
public final class References{
    static String refSearched = "custom";

    public static boolean methodControl1(final String s){
        return s.contains(refSearched);
    }    
    .... // other fields/methods
}

    // In other classes
    if(References.methodControl1(newStringToSearchIn)){
        ..;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the strings like `"custom"` pre-defined? If the number of such strings are limited, then you would also profit by making them into methods such as `Manager.hasCustom()` if not, you can go for `Manager.has(Manager.CUSTOM)` where `CUSTOM` could be an attribute in the `Manager` class.

Consider memoizing the lookup.

```
class Manager {
  public final String CUSTOM = "custom";
  public boolean has(String key) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) map.put(StringUtils.contains(name, key))
    return map.get(key);
  }
  public boolean hasCustom() { return has(CUSTOM); }
}
```

Finally, if your class takes decisions based on a flag in another class, you might want to rewrite it to reduce coupling. And perhaps use a pattern like [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).